# Exception "The connection manager is shutdown" Java7 / JBoss 6.2 EAP (Server not shutting down)

Tags: java, exception, jdbc, jboss, spring-jdbc

I have a strange behaviour on a Java7 web application deployed under a JBoss 6.2 EAP. 
I have two database instances (Oracle 10) that are almost identical (same structure but different data). This two instances are interchangeble without problems for all applications that work on them, but for a particular application when I switch ONLY the connection string of the datasource created on JBoss for that application, the application stops working and I get a SQLException "The connection manager is shutdown". Obviously neither the DB nor the AS are shutting down when I get the exception. If I switch back to the other DB instance, all works fine.
The only thing that I change is the connection URL for the data-source (and I restart JBoss).
Application uses Spring JDBC.

Any idea on what's happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if both instances are up and working? You can use SQLDeveloper or a simple JDBC program to check if the connection is fine. Later, you can add JBOSS changes.

Comment: They are up and working, and other applications seem to work fine on both. On JBOSS the only thing that I change is the Connection URL of the DataSource. Thanks.